# Install GD extension in php8 from alpine 3.13

Tags: docker, gd, php-8

I have added the following code in my Dockerfile

```
RUN echo -e "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main\nhttp://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community" > /etc/apk/repositories;
RUN apk add --no-cache gd;
```

I ran the command

```
docker-compose build
```

The build was successful, but when I restart my docker php8 image
I still get the error - No GD module found.

I have enabled the GD extension in my php.ini file
but I get this error

[Error After enabling GD extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQSRl.png)

Answer (score 5):

following this answer install gd from dockerfile

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

https://github.com/rhamdeew/docker-php-8-fpm-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: It fails with errors about missing libraries. Could you extend your answer?